# How can I apply variable to css in VueJS [no inline-styling]

Tags: css, vue.js, variables

I want to create a background color of body element that will dynamically change based on this.linearGradient. As you might see it should change a part of linear-gradient instead of replacing the entire linear-gradient. No inline-styling allows.

```js
computed: {
  backgroundStyle () {
    return {
      '--linearGradient': this.linearGradient
    }
  }
},

<style>
background: linear-gradient(145.74deg, #9BDBFF -33.02%, #B4DEDA 52.01%, #FFD66B  var(--linearGradient)7.04%);
</style>
```

```html
  <body :style="backgroundStyle">
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below snippet.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: '<div>bg-color<br/>Applied<input type="text" v-model="linearGradient" /></div>',
  data() {
    return {
      linearGradient: '#FFD66B'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    linearGradient: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(oldValue, newValue) {
        document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(145.74deg, #9BDBFF -33.02%, #B4DEDA 52.01%,  ${oldValue} 7.04%)`
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    backgroundStyle: function() {
      return {
        background: `linear-gradient(145.74deg, #9BDBFF -33.02%, #B4DEDA 52.01%,  ${this.linearGradient} 7.04%)`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How do I pass this to parent element. body element is in index.html instead of component....

Comment: document.body.style.background contains a typo....but nevertheless this is exactly what I was looking for...